# How do I wrap a service so it is simpler

Tags: c#, design-patterns, programming-practices, code-reviews, wrapper

We have a dependency to a third-party service which exposes a gigantic interface of which we only need like 3 methods. Additionally, the interface changes frequently...

I've decided to wrap the interface in a class in our project and only expose the methods that we need.

But I'm unsure how I should handle the return values...
The interface returns an object of type `Storage`. We internally have a type `StorageModel` which is our internal representation of a `Storage`.

What would you return in the mapper: `Storage` or `StorageModel`?
We have a DataService `StorageService` which get a dependency of the wrapper injected.

Currently I'm doing it basically like this:

```
public class StorageService 
{
    private readonly IExternalStorageWrapper externalStorageWrapper;

    public StorageService(IExternalStorageWrapper externalStorageWrapper)
    {
        this.externalStorageWrapper = externalStorageWrapper;
    }

    public StorageModel GetStorage(int storageId)
    {
        return this.externalStorageWrapper.GetStorage(storageId).ConvertToStorageModel();
    }
}

public class ExternalStorageWrapper : IExternalStorageWrapper
{
    public Storage GetStorage(int storageId)
    {
        using(var ext = new ExternalStorage())
        {
            return ext.GetStorage(storageId);
        }
    }
}
```

What would you say:

- Is it good like above, that the wrapper returns the external `Storage` object and the internal `StorageService` returns the internal `StorageModel`?
- Or would you return a `StorageModel` in the wrapper already?

Comment: Why do you name it a wrapper? Better look for the facade-, bridge- and adapter-pattern. As I understand, a wrapper would provide all methods of the third-party service - but that is not what you want.

Comment: Recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/)**.

Comment: @TobiasOtto a wrapper doesn't need to expose all of the wrapped object's behavior, see [this article](https://8thlight.com/blog/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html) in "A limited wrapper".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my optinion, the wrapper should deal with all things related to the external library. This means that the public interface of the Wrapper must not name any external types.

Mapping external types to the respective types of your application is part of the wrapper's duties. If this is not a trivial operation, then you may use the various tools available to decompose the problem, e.g. injecting a translator object. However, the translator must still be part of your wrapper module, and no other part of your application may depend on it.

This way, the rest of your application is completely immune not only to changes in the library, but also to replacements of the library for another one.

Answer (score 4):

> I've decided to wrap the interface in a class in our project and only
>   expose the methods that we need.

That's ok. This is also known as [Adapter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

You choose the *Adapter* pattern, so the aim here is *transforming* one *interface* (library model) into another (domain model). So,  if something from the former reaches the domain model, [the adapter is failing to its purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11079605/5934037).

According to the previous arguments, the adapter should return the `StorageModel`.

Ultimately, your domain "speaks" a specific language, where `Storage` is a *[stranger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32251787/5934037)*.

> But I'm unsure how I should handle the return values...

The key here is to know **for what reason you are *wrapping/adapting* the library**.

Adapter, Decorator, Facade patterns might have similarities but they are fairly different. As different as the problems they solve.

That said, you might be also interested in:

- [Facade pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) *(hiding complexity)*
- [Decorator pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) *(interface enhancement)*. [When to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549743/5934037)
- [Differences between Adapter pattern and Proxy Pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/201405/222996).
- [What's an anti-corruption layer and how it's used](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/184464/222996) *(hiding low quality and messy code)*

Answer (score 1):

You can't effectively wrap a library by duplicating it.

What you should wrap is you usage of the library and that means not exposing it objects, in this case Storage. Don't try to duplicate them either.

Use the library, but keep it contained. So in your case, assuming your using the StorageService to store things you should wrap it in repositories

```
MyPocoObjectRepo
    MyPocoObject GetObject(string id);
```

where MyPocoObject is entirely your data and business logic. Not a duplication of Storage or a DataReader or anything

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it depends on whether or not you ever need to access `Storage` directly from a class that isn't `StorageModel`.

If you're going to wrap the library, it makes sense to also wrap the object returned by it to let you future proof changes made by the library in the future.  However if you ever need to use `Storage` directly, it means there *may* be need to return `Storage` according to the situation.  An argument could be said for obliging `Storage` usage here to be `StorageModel` as you likely want to remain consistent throughout your program.

I would strongly recommend you wrap both the interface and the returned object if you're not already doing so, though again, that only makes sense if you're only using `StorageModel` throughout your program and not `Storage`.